Не определяются параметры мета пикселя фейсбук
Всем привет! Такая проблема: не определяются параметры пикселя и не детектятся события в ивент менеджере фб. С фронта все ок, фиксирует. А вот от сервака, непонятно что.
Additional conversions reported
​
from the Conversions API (server)
Send this event with your Meta Pixel to see additional conversions reported results.
Parameters
​
No event parameters were detected. Use Test Events to view the parameters of an individual event trigger.

Вот, что говорит сам пиксель. Еще интересное наблюдение: Connection Method не Conversion API, а Server. И вот сам код отправки события:
def send_event(invite_link):
    pixel_id = get_data_from_db(invite_link, 'pixel_id')[0]
    pixel_api = get_pixel_api(pixel_id)

    FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=pixel_api)

    client_ip_address = get_data_from_db(invite_link, 'client_ip_address')[0]
    client_user_agent = get_data_from_db(invite_link, 'client_user_agent')[0]

    user_data = UserData(
        emails=['joe@eg.com'],
        phones=['12345678901', '14251234567'],
        client_ip_address=client_ip_address,
        client_user_agent=client_user_agent,
        fbc='fb.1.1554763741205.AbCdEfGhIjKlMnOpQrStUvWxYz1234567890',
        fbp='fb.1.1558571054389.1098115397',
    )

    event_data = Event(
        event_name='Subscribe',
        event_time=int(time.time()),
        event_source_url='https://tgprojectredirect.top/',
        user_data=user_data,
        action_source=ActionSource.WEBSITE,
    )

    try:
        events = [event_data]
        event_request = EventRequest(
            events=events,
            pixel_id=pixel_id
        )

        event_response = event_request.execute()
        print(event_response)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return {"status": 'error', "error": str(e)}```


Вывод с кода: 
```
{
  'events_received': 1,
  'fbtrace_id': 'A_l-o3Ya92WWNkP8OV4YoBa',
  'messages': []
}
```



При создание выбирают Setup manual API, а параметры: Event time, Event name, Event Source URL, Aciton source, Event id, Cpient IP Address, Client User Agent, Click ID (fbc) Cookie
 

